# Oracle PL/SQL Contar personas por año de servicio

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una tabla como la siguiente:

employee_id employee_name job manager_id hiredate salary:

7369         SMITH        CLERK 7902 28/09/15 1400

Me piden contar los empleados y sus años de servicio

Ejemplo de Salida de datos:

Entre 1 y 4 años: 2 Trabajadores

Entre 5 y 6 años: 4 Trabajadores

Entre 7 a más años 9 Trabajadores

Esto es lo que se me ha ocurrido hasta el momento

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE

AñosT Int := 0;

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT (employee_name) INTO AñosT FROM employees WHERE (2020-EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hiredate))<7;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (AñosT||' Trabajadores'||', Continuar laborando');

END;
```

Por favor, alguien sepa esto, seria de gran ayuda para mí.

Comment: Hola, puedes decirme si la respuesta te sirvio

Answer (score 0):

```
Select count(employe_name) as total, (2020 - extract(year from hiredate)) as Años 
from employees 
group by (2020 - extract(year from hiredate))
```

Se hace una consulta donde se va a obtener el total de trabajadores según su tiempo de servicio, para ello se utiliza la cláusula group by, la cual agrupa por los años de servicio del trabajador, la cónsulta muestra el total de trabajadores y su tiempo de servicio, te recomiendo que investigues en internet sobre la cláusula group by